# How to generate the dll from the perl file?

Tags: perl, dll

I have one .pl file(perl file) I need to generate the .dll for that perl file,I don't know how to generate can any one help me ?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense as such - can you explain more broadly what you are trying to do?  For example, are you trying to located a missing dll, create a plugin using perl, etc..?

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking to make a Windows executable out of your Perl file? [This PerlMonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=215299) suggests some ways of doing it, and gives a tutorial on how to use [the App::Packer CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=App::Packer).

Are you looking to use Perl code from another language such as C? Then [the perlembed tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) may be of use.

Are you looking to make a DLL out of a Perl file for some other reason? Other solutions on [this PerlMonks node where someone asks the same question as you](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=804286) may also be useful.

First, though, think about why it is that you need to make a DLL from a Perl file. If it's not for one of these reasons, and you don't need other programming languages to be able to call that Perl file and its functions, think about whether you need to do anything further than just running the file with the Perl interpreter.